# Error after running Kali Linux update command

Tags: linux, kali-linux, apt

I have downloaded the Kali Linux image and Kali Linux VM image more than 7 times but it shows same error ever time I run the `apt-get update` command  after installing properly.

```
Get:1 http://ftp.yzu.edu.tw/Linux/kali kali-rolling InRelease [30.5 kB]

Err:1 http://ftp.yzu.edu.tw/Linux/kali kali-rolling InRelease

  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>

Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://ftp.yzu.edu.tw/Linux/kali kali-rolling InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your archive-keyring package is out of date, so you need to add the new repository key to your system:

```
wget -q -O - https://archive.kali.org/archive-key.asc  | apt-key add
```

Comment: This appears to have been tweeted recently by Kali Linux: https://twitter.com/kalilinux/status/959515084157538304 (thanks to Ben F for commenting in a now deleted answer)